# Silex - InvalidArgumentException in ControllerResolver

Tags: php, silex

Hi. I'm new to Silex (2.0), and I'm trying to pass the $app variable to my Controller, so I'm trying to create my Controller as a service.

I am following the [documentation guide](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/service_controller.html), but when registering my Controller I get an error of the type: InvalidArgumentException: Class "controller. default" does not exist.

[image]

On my index.php:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
// Register controller as services.
$app['controller.default'] = function() use ($app) {
    return new Fortunio\Controller\DefaultController($app);
};
$app->get('/', "controller.default::indexAction");
```

If I change the last line of code, the application runs smoothly and the error disappears:

```
$app->get('/', 'Fortunio\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction');
```

On my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Fortunio\Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController
{
    public function indexAction(Application $app, Request $request)
    {
        // my controller code here
    }
}
```

Where's my mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: nicely put-together question.

As far as I can see yer following the docs, so if they claim that should work: your code should work. That said, this is *not* the approach we take with using controllers as services. Our approach is more like this:

```
class ControllerProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Application $app)
    {
        $app['controller.thing'] = function ($app) {
            return new ThingController();
        };
    }
}

class RouteProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface 
{
    public function register(Application $app)
    {
        $app->get('/thing/{id}/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
            return $app['controller.thing']->doGET($request);
        })->assert('id', '\d+');
    }
}

use Silex\Application as SilexApplication;

class Application extends SilexApplication
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->register(new ControllerProvider());
        $this->register(new RouteProvider());
    }
}

$app = new Application();
```

The key difference is this bit, in the RouteProvider:

```
$app->get('/thing/{id}/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['controller.thing']->doGET($request);
})->assert('id', '\d+');
```

See we don't use the string reference to the controller service (ie: just `controller.thing:doGET`), we use the actual reference to the controller in the DI container, and actually call the method in the closure.

I want to check if they docs version actually works, but I need to get back to my day job. I'll have a fiddle with it later on and come back with findings as to whether I get it working or not. I def *have* had the `controller.thing:doGET` approach working in the past, but even then my approach (using Silex 1.x) was slightly different. It's in a blog article here: [PHP: Silex Controller Providers](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2015/04/php-silex-controller-providers.html), but I would not recommend that approach any more. I include it just to demonstrate that that syntax can be made to work.

Comment: Hi @AdamCameron, thank you very much for your help, as you mentioned, if the instructions in the reference guide are followed correctly there should be no problems. My mistake was in using the colon (:), since using the controller by its name and action uses the syntax My\Controller::myAction (with double colon) but using the Controller as a service should use only one colon 'my.controller:myAction'. 
When I corrected the use of the colon the error disappears and the application runs smoothly.
Greetings!

Comment: Haha, I so didn't spot that! Not a great error message for the given situation eh? Glad you got it sorted.